# If stack.top() returns a reference, then why doesn't this code work?

Tags: c++, stl, struct

I'm trying to peek the top element of my stack of structs to change its properties:

```
stack<mat> stk;
...
mat parent = stk.top();
parent.cap -= n;
```

But this doesn't change the value on the top of the stack.  I think this is just changing the value of a copy.  Instead I had to do something like this (I'm not sure if it's right, but it works):

```
stack<mat> stk;
...
mat * parent = &stk.top();
parent->cap -= n;
```

I read in the reference that `stk.top()` returns a reference to the element on the top of the stack, so why doesn't my first example work?

Comment: `parent` isn't a reference...

Comment: You should use a reference on the calling side as well... `mat &parent = stk.top();`...

Comment: At this point I'd like to blame the use of overly colloquial language for this beginner's mistake: Functions never "return references". Rather, *evaluating a function call expression always produces a value*, and values are never references. The distinction is whether the return *type* of the function is a reference or not, and correspondingly whether the produced value is an lvalue or an rvalue. This sounds more complicated, but avoids mental missteps like this.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I didn't know that I had to declare my variable as a reference.  I assumed that it would be like a function returning a reference in Java, which is wrong.

Comment: @Duncan Moral: never assume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, you're copying your ref into a new `mat` object:

```
mat parent = stk.top();
```

If you want to work on a reference, use a reference like this:

```
mat& parent = stk.top();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mat parent = stk.top(); // Will only copy the data into a new object
```

The class mat seems to have an operator= implemented so that it can make a copy from another objects values.

What this line actually does is returning a reference to the object on top and then copying it's data to the newly on stack created object mat parent.

And if you change parent values they will have no impact on the original object in your stack.

H2CO3 above is right:

```
mat &parent = stk.top(); // gives you a handle to your top stacked object
```

is the way to go for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these code

```
mat parent = stk.top();
parent.cap -= n;
```

You could write simply

```
stk.top().cap -= n;
```

In the first case you define a new object parent that contains a copy of the state of the object in the stack.